# Is "BAC+n" understood in Finland?

Tags: finland

I am from France and want to find an internship in Finland.

Can I use "BAC+n" on my resume? Will it be understood or should I use something else? Maybe the terms License and Master are enough since it is supposedly known in all Europe but this is relatively recent so I think it would hurt to add BAC+5.

Comment: Generally speaking, I'd say that "BAC+n" wouldn't be understood by anyone not familiar with the French system.

Comment: I second what Massimo says.  I assumed you were talking about some sort of new-fangled not-meat form of bacon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ECTS was created precisely for this kind of issue. If you think there is any doubt, just say how many ECTS your degrees are worth. In any case, the Bologna process started about 20 years ago. I think by now everyone knows the lingo. Be aware that the first degree is usually called "bachelor", though. Bac+5 is master's degree, so if you do have a master's degree, just say so.

In any case I would be very surprised if "bac+n" was understood in Finland. You should realize that "bac" refers to "*baccalauréat*", the French high school diploma. Even assuming that someone understand that "bac+n" means "n years after the bac", they are very likely to think that "bac" is "bachelor", the French "*licence*"... And "bac+n" is hardly a useful metric anyway, the content of the degree matters much more.

Answer (score 5):

I am not a Finn; but I grew up 200 km from France, and I have no idea what it means either.

**You can count on everyone in the academic world understanding only the three words bachelor, master, phd**. Everything else, nope, unless they are familiar with how that country's university system works. So make sure you put one or more of those three words on your CV.

Answer (score 4):

I am Finnish and have never heard the term "BAC+n", and have little idea what it would mean. Maybe it is related to bachelor's degree, with "n" signifying quality by some measurment? I have a PhD, but no experience hiring people or accepting students or interns.

Comment: The post describes my state of knowledge before reading the other answer, obviously.